# High performing container for storing a high number of objects

Tags: algorithm, performance, containers

I am looking for an ideal data container for with following objectives:

The behavior of the container must be sort of like Queue, with the following specifications:

1) random access is not a must
2) iterating over the objects in two directions must be super fast ( contiguous data would be better)
3) high performing delete from the front of the list and insert in the back is a must ( a high number of deletes and appends are done at every time step )
4) items are not primitive types, they are objects.

I know double-linked lists are not high performing containers.
vectors (like std::vector in c++) are good, but it is not really optimized for deleting from the front, also I don't think vectorization is possible at all given the size of objects.

I was also looking at the possibility of Slot-Map container, but not sure if it is the best option.

I was wondering if there are better options available?

Comment: Roughly how large is each object, how much data do you plan to store in total and when you say "a high number of deletes" what kind of number do you expect that to be and in what time frame? It could help in determining what you may/may not be able to get away with.

Comment: each object is sizeof(double) * 32, around 100 inserts, and 100 deletes at each time. but the container can have thousands (10k) of objects stored.

Comment: (This relies on your destructor not actually "doing" anything - disregard if not the case) I'd suggest using a vector, and keeping track of the "head" index. When you insert into the back, it will perform well. When erasing from the front, don't actually delete the element, just increment the head index (and imagine the elements before this do not exist now). When you eventually need to free space, use std::remove to help erase all the front elements together in an efficient way.

Comment: 10k is tiny. Any old deque would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get away with just a regular `vector` and a `start` index that tells you where the "real" beginning of your data is.

- to append to the back, use the regular method. This has an amortized constant-time complexity, which is probably fine for you given that you will be doing lots of pushing.
- to delete from the front, increment `start`.
- to access element `i`, use `vector[start + i]`.
- whenever you delete from anywhere but the front, or insert anywhere except the back, go ahead and recreate the whole vector without any leading deleted entries and reset `start` to zero.

Pros:

- entries are in a contiguous chunk of memory
- fast delete from the front and (amortized) fast insert into the back
- fast random access and fast iteration

Cons:

- slow worst-case insertion behavior
- potentially lots of wasted space unless cleaned up periodically
- cleaning up on deletes changes delete's worst-case behavior to linear, slow.

Whatever you do, consider comparing to the natural approach: a doubly-linked list with the head and tail remembered.

- fast inserts/deletes from the front/back
- no wasted space

True, the items will not be contiguous in memory so there is a potential for more cache misses; however, you could combat this with occasional *defragmentation*:

- allocate enough contiguous space for all nodes in the list
- recreate nodes in order by traversing links
- release the original nodes and use the new set of nodes as the list

Depending on the pattern of deletes/inserts/traversals, this could be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

If we really care about the performance, the container should never allocate any memory dynamically, i.e. we should define an upper limit of objects in the container.

The interface requirements is queueish indeed, so it looks like the fastest option would be circular queue of pointers to objects. So the container should shave the following fields:

1. `OBJECT * ptrs[SIZE]` -- fixed size array of pointers. Sure, we will waste `SIZE * sizeof (OBJECT *)` bytes here, but performance wise it could be a good trade.
2. `size_t head_idx` -- head object index.
3. `size_t tail_idx` -- tail object index.

> iterating over the objects in two directions must be super fast

Next object is a next index in the `ptrs[]`:

```
if (cur_idx >= head_idx) return nullptr;
return ptrs[(cur_idx++) % SIZE]; // make sure SIZE is a power of 2 constant
```

Prev object is a prev index in the `ptrs[]`:

```
if (cur_idx <= tail_idx) return nullptr;
return ptrs[(cur_idx--) % SIZE]; // make sure SIZE is a power of 2 constant
```

> high performing delete from the front of the list and insert in the back is a must

The pop_front() would be as simple as:

```
if (tail_idx == head_idx) ... // should not happen, through an error
head_idx++;
```

The push_back() would be as simple as:

```
if (tail_idx - head_idx >= SIZE) ... // should not happen, through an error
ptrs[(tail_idx++) % SIZE] = obj_ptr; // make sure SIZE if a power of 2 constant
```

> items are not primitive types, they are objects

The most generic solution would be to simply store pointers in the cyclic queue, so the size of the object does not matter and you waste just SIZE times pointer, not SIZE times object. But sure, if you can afford to preallocate thousands of objects, it should be even faster...

Those are kind of speculations based on your performance requirements. I am not sure if you can afford to trade some memory for the performance, so I am sorry if it is not the case...